# How to update multiple values in Mongodb using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb

In my code when a process starts the following data are stored in my core_pid table.

```
db.core_pid.insert({"blog_id": blog["_id"], "proid": str(p.pid), "starttime": datetime.now(pytz.timezone('EST')), "status": "Running", "route":routing})
```

After the process is completed i updated the value of status using the below code.

```
db.core_pid.update({"_id": current_id},
                       {"$set": {"status": "Completed"}})
```

Now i want to include a new field endtime in database when process is completed ({"endtime": datetime.now(pytz.timezone('EST'))}).How can i alter the above update code to include this endtime field too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply, include the "endtime" field in "$set" value

```
db.core_pid.update({"_id": current_id},
                   {"$set": {
                       "status": "Completed",
                       "endtime": datetime.now(pytz.timezone('EST'))}})
```

Comment: Thanks man. I tried this and it didn't worked before. I thought the query was wrong. The Actual problem was with the variable current_id. Now its working..

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the other field as an argument to $set:

```
b.core_pid.update({"_id": current_id},
    {"$set": { 
        "status": "Completed",
        "endtime": datetime.now(pytz.timezone('EST')) 
    }})
```

And that will just update both of those fields in the document without touching others.